# Get elements between two elements in an F# collection

Tags: f#

I'd like to take a List or Array, and given two elements in the collection, get all elements between them. But I want to do this in a circular fashion, such that given a list `[1;2;3;4;5;6]`  and if I ask for the elements that lie between 4 then 2, I get back `[5;6;1]`

Being used to imperative programming I can easily do this with loops, but I imagine there may be a nicer idiomatic approach to it in F#.

**Edit**

Here is an approach I came up with, having found the Array.indexed function

```
let elementsBetween (first:int) (second:int) (elements: array<'T>) =
    let diff = second - first
    elements 
    |> Array.indexed
    |> Array.filter (fun (index,element) -> if diff = 0 then false
                                            else if diff > 0 then index > first && index < second
                                            else if diff < 0 then index > first || index < second
                                            else false
```

This approach will only work with arrays obviously but this seems pretty good. I have a feeling I could clean it up by replacing the if/then/else with pattern matching but am not sure how to do that cleanly.

Comment: You need to provide your attempt. While most of us can easily answer this, you need to show your effort. As such I am giving this a down vote.

Comment: What should happen in case of duplicates? What if one of the limit values aren't found?

Comment: Thanks for showing your attempt. I reversed my down vote.

Comment: duplicates are ok. Limit values not being found should be an error. I don't need exact code for this just some general approaches.

Comment: A variation of this would be to use list slicing, e.g. <someList>.[(first+1) .. (second-1)].

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses, they are all helpful.  I may have to select an official answer partly at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variation using your idea of diff with list and list slicing
`<some list.[x .. y]`

```
let between (first : int) (second : int) (l : 'a list) : 'a list =
    if first < 0 then
        failwith "first cannot be less than zero"
    if second < 0 then
        failwith "second cannot be less than zero"
    if first > (l.Length * 2) then
        failwith "first cannot be greater than length of list times 2"
    if second > (l.Length * 2) then
        failwith "second cannot be greater than length of list times 2"

    let diff = second - first
    match diff with
    | 0 -> []
    | _ when diff > 0 && (abs diff) < l.Length -> l.[(first + 1) .. (second - 1)]
    | _ when diff > 0 -> (l@l).[(first + 1) .. (second - 1)]
    | _ when diff < 0 && (abs diff) < l.Length -> l.[(second + 1)  .. (second + first - 1)]
    | _ when diff < 0 -> (l@l).[(second + 1)  .. (second + first - 1)]
```

Comment: This looks like it will only work if `first` is both the index and the value of the first element. Perhaps I misunderstood, but I thought that `[1;2;3;4;5;6]` was only an example. I do not think that this will work for an arbitrary buffer such as `[11;13;14;16]`. This needs the list to start with 0 `[0;1;2;3;4;5;6]`

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I did not check the code for exact correctness because the OP stated in a comment `I don't need exact code for this just some general approaches.`. Since the answer is CC feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not on my normal computer with an f# compiler, so I haven't tested it yet. It should look something like this

[Edit] Thank you @FoggyFinder for showing me https://dotnetfiddle.net/. I have now tested the code below with it.

[Edit] This should find the circular range in a single pass.

```
let x = [1;2;3;4;5]
let findCircRange l first second =
    let rec findUpTo (l':int list) f (s:int) : (int list * int list) = 
        match l' with 
        | i::tail -> 
            if i = s then tail, (f [])
            else findUpTo tail (fun acc -> f (i::acc)) s
        // In case we are passed an empty list.
        | _ -> [], (f [])
    let remainder, upToStart = findUpTo l id first
    // concatenate the list after start with the list before start. 
    let newBuffer = remainder@upToStart
    snd <| findUpTo newBuffer id second

let values = findCircRange x 4 2
printf "%A" values
```

findUpTo takes a list (l'), a function for creating a remainder list (f) and a value to look for (s). We recurse through it (tail recursion) to find the list up to the given value and the list after the given value. Wrap the buffer around by appending the end to the remainder. Pass it to the findUpTo again to find up to the end. Return the buffer up to the end.

We pass a function for accumulating found items. This technique allows us to append to the end of the list as the function calls unwind.

Of course, there is no error checking here. We are assuming that start and end do actually exist. That will be left to an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, it is good to see an approach both for Lists and Arrays.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thank you. I usually use www.tryfsharp.com, but it requires an install that I didn't have on that computer.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at MSDN, Collections.Seq Module for example.

Let's try to be clever:

```
let elementsBetween a e1 e2 =
    let aa = a |> Seq.append a
    let i1 = aa |> Seq.findIndex (fun e -> e = e1)
    let i2 = aa |> Seq.skip i1 |> Seq.findIndex (fun e -> e = e2)
    aa |> Seq.skip(i1+1) |> Seq.take(i2-1)
```